# Spring boot exception handling with controller advice and hosting static pages

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am developing a Spring Boot REST API. It uses `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler` in a class that extends `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` to catch exceptions. To get this to work, we added these two fields to the config:

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found: true

spring.resources.add-mapping: false
```

The problem is I am also trying to host static documents that I would like spring to map. I added this to my config:

```
spring.resources.static-locations: classpath:/static/html5/,classpath:/public/html5/
```

It seems I cant set mapping to false and map static resources. If I dont set add-mapping to false, I can't catch 404s.

Is there a spring way to solve this? If not, I am going to try to define an endpoint for each static resource and find the files in the jar, which seems like a hack.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Just found an open issue on spring-boot's github. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7653

Comment: any solution found ?

Comment: @SimonLudwig I created a controller to host static pages. Not ideal, but it works. Still waiting on a fix from spring.